# Get size of string pointed to by a position memory pointer

Tags: c++

I want to get characters of a string pointed by a position memory pointer in native C++:

For an equivalent implementation in C#, it will be:

```
int positionMemory = getPosition();

long size = 10;

string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new IntPtr(positionMemory), size);
```

How can I produce the result in C++?

Comment: By "string", do you mean "null-terminated sequence of characters"?

Comment: `std::string result = static_cast<const char*>(positionMemory);`

Comment: @MooingDuck but that will cast an int to a string right?

Comment: @olidev: if it's not, it has to be delimited somehow, or it would be impossible to tell the length.  Normally, "strings" are null terminated.

Comment: @olidev: it will create a string based on the characters at the position in memory represented by `positionMemory`, assuming they are null terminated.

Comment: @MooingDuck perhaps also mention that positionMemory will not be an int, but either `void *` or `char *` or constants of those. olidev where do you get `positionMemory` from in your C++ program?

Comment: @d_inevitable: I made assumptions based on the provided sample code.  The code I provided works in all the cases you mention, including the insane/stupid ones.

Comment: @MooingDuck didnt say otherwise, but won't the compiler get upset if `void *` goes `int`? We dont know where `getPosition()` comes from. :)

Comment: @olidev: The question title doesn't match the text at all.  Are you trying to get the characters, or the length (or both?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling this is going to cause problems down the road...

The following should be more or less equivalent to the C# snippet you gave with the exception that the resulting string (stored in `result`) will still be 'ANSI' - it is not widened to UNICODE as would occur in the C# snippet.

```
int positionMemory = getPosition();
long size = 10;

std::string result( reinterpret_cast<const char *>(positionMemory), size);
```

Note that `size` characters will be placed in `result` - including `'/0'` characters, so if you try to pass the string to something expecting a C-style sting using `c_str()` you may get some unexpected results.

Also, the usual caveats about using an `int` as a pointer (especially if you want this to have a hope of working on a 64-bit system) apply.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "string" is a sequence of `char`s at the position in memory represented by `positionMemory` that is null terminated, you can get the length via `strlen`

```
const char* str = static_cast<const char*>(positionMemory);
int length = strlen(str);
```

However, judging by your demo code which creates a string, this is probably what you want, and is far better code:

```
std::string result = static_cast<const char*>(positionMemory);
int length = result.length();
```